# Import external JS into Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

I am writing application in Angular 8 (8.0.3) and I need to import external JS file which will hold a URL reference for API that can and will change. The problem I am facing is that changes I do into this file after I have compiled Angular app (with ng build --prod), changes are not being picked up inside Angular, but it keeps the data as it was when the app was built.

This is the external JS file:

```
export function apiUrl() {
    return 'http://www.localhost.local/api/v1/';
}
```

The `apiUrl()` does return proper value, but if I change it, the updated value is not reflected inside Angular app.

I also created `.d.ts.` file:

```
export declare function apiUrl();
```

Imported the external JS file into index.html:

```
<script type="module" src="assets/js/api_url.js"></script>
```

Used it in angular service:

```
import {apiUrl} from '../../assets/js/api_url';
export class ApiService {

    private api_url: string = apiUrl();

    constructor(...) {
        console.log(apiUrl());
    }
}
```

I did NOT import this file in `angular.json` and even if I do, nothing changes.

So, how to create and then import an external JS file that after it changes, the Angular app does pick up it changes?

EDIT:
Do note that I do not need a live app reload when this file changes, but I need for the file to be loaded from server each time the Angular app starts.

EDIT 2:
To explain why I need this. The Angular app will be used on internal network to which I do not have access to. The client currently does not know the API URL and even if he would, it can change at any moment. That's the reason why I need this to work.

Comment: ng build doesn't watch for file changes. Only ng serve does.  If you make changes to files after build you have to rebuild your project

Comment: I am aware of that but I need a solution that will pick up changes in this file and this file only. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you should use **[environments](https://angular.io/guide/build)**

You can find them in `src/environments` directory.

For local development you have `environment.ts` file, for production `environment.prod.ts`

Example `environment.ts`:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'http://www.localhost.local/api/v1/'
};
```

`environment.prod.ts`:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiUrl: 'http://www.producitonurl.com/api/v1/'
};
```

To use this `apiUrl` value you need to import environment file in typescript file like this:
**You need to import `environment.ts` not any other environment file, because angular is replacing it while building application**

```
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyApiService {
    apiUrl = environment.apiUrl;
}
```

But in case you want to use method from `<script type="module" src="assets/js/api_url.js"></script>`, just use `window` object like this:

```
private api_url: string = (window as any).apiUrl();
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the solution I was looking for. I am aware of environments but in this case, they are not usefull.

Comment: You can still use method from script file by using `window` scope, but i'm not sure about this `export function`

Comment: I mentioned this in the last sentence in my answer :)